# How to decrease table font size

Tags: tables, math-mode, fonts

I am struggling to create two column, full page table. For now I made the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=13mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l c}
        \toprule
            y & y' \\
            \midrule
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But it has awful big font for some reason and I'll need ~20 rows of small math expressions. I am latex newbie so probably something simple is missing.

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: It's a very narrow table, which gets then resized to `\columnwidth`. What's the purpose of the `\resizebox`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek If I don't use resizebox it won't be full page table. I am trying to create my calculus cheatsheet. :/ With functions in first column and derivatives in second.

Comment: Scaling to the desired height instead of width might be an option.

Comment: Use `tabularx` to get a full page width table.

Comment: never use `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%` on tables, you could of course make it full width by putting lots of space between the columns but that just makes it harder to read, why not let the table be natural width but centred on the page.

Comment: "it has awful big font" not for "some reason", just for the **resize** box.  Just remove it and you will have enough vertical space  for more that 20 rows and the right font size.  If  some table witdth is a must, use \for example `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c}` or `tabularx` or tabulary` packages, but as David  pointed, not always is  good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible solutions here (discussed in the comments).

The first is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=13mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c}
        \toprule
            y & y' \\
            \midrule
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

The second is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=13mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
    \begin{tabular}{l c}
        \toprule
            y & y' \\
            \midrule
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

The third is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=13mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
  \resizebox{!}{391pt}{
    \begin{tabular}{l c}
        \toprule
            y & y' \\
            \midrule
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

(It's hard to tell from the picture, but it fills up the whole page and doesn't overflow.)

The fourth is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=13mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% ...

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ XXXXXXX }
            \toprule
            y & y' \\
            \midrule
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
            as & well \\
            using & the \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

I may be incorrectly spacing the `tabularx` option, but even still, I personally think the third option is the best option.

Thanks to all the commenters (Fran, David Carlisle, Johannes_B, and Heiko Oberdiek) for their suggestions.

Finally, in light of your comments, I'm working on a solution to what you really want to create. So far, I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=13mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
% ...

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \small
  \resizebox{520pt}{320pt}{%
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      Derivatives and Integrals \\
      \\
      \toprule
      Basic Differentiation Rules \\
      \midrule
      \\
      1. $\frac {d}{dx} [cu] = cu'$ & 2. $\frac{d}{dx} [u \pm v] = u' \pm 
      v'$ \\
      3. $\frac{d}{dx} [uv] = uv' + vu'$ & 4. $\frac{d}{dx} [\frac{u}{v}] 
      = \frac{vu' - uv'}{v^2}$ \\
      5. $\frac{d}{dx} [c] = 0$ & 6. $\frac{d}{dx} [u^n] = nu^{n-1} \quad 
      u'$ \\
      7. $\frac{d}{dx} [x] = 1$ & 8. $\frac{d}{dx} [\mid u \mid] = 
      \frac{u}{\mid u \mid} (u'), \quad u \neq 0$ \\
      9. $\frac{d}{dx} [ln \quad u] = \frac{u'}{u}$ & 10. $\frac{d}{dx} 
      [e^u] = e^u \quad u'$ \\
      11. $\frac{d}{dx} [sin \quad u] = (cos \quad u) u'$ & 12. $\frac{d}
      {dx} [cos \quad u] = -(sin \quad u) u'$ \\
      13. $\frac{d}{dx} [tan \quad u] = (sec^2 \quad u)u'$ & 14. 
      $\frac{d}{dx} [cot \quad u] = -(csc^2 \quad u) u'$ \\
      15. $\frac{d}{dx} [sec \quad u] = (sec \quad u \quad tan \quad u) 
      u'$ & 16. $\frac{d}{dx} [csc \quad u] = -(csc \quad u \quad cot 
      \quad u) u'$ \\
      17. $\frac{d}{dx} [arcsin \quad u] = \frac{u'}{\sqrt{-1 - u^2}}$ & 
      18. $\frac{d}{dx} [arccos \quad u] = \frac{-u'}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ \\
      19. $\frac{d}{dx} [arctan \quad u] = \frac{u'}{1 + u^2}$ & 20. 
      $\frac{d}{dx} [arccot \quad u] = \frac{-u'}{1 + u^2}$ \\
      21. $\frac{d}{dx} [arcsec \quad u] = \frac{u'}{\mid u \mid 
      \sqrt{u^2 - 1}}$ & 22. $\frac{d}{dx} [arcsec \quad u] = \frac{-u'}
      {\mid u \mid \sqrt{u^2 - 1}}$ \\
      \\
      Basic Integration Formulas \\
      \\
      1. $\int k \quad f(u) \quad d u = k \int f(u) \quad du$ & 2. $\int 
      \quad [f(u) \pm g (u)] \quad du = \int f(u) \quad du \pm \int g(u) 
      \quad du$ \\
      3. $\int  d u = u + C$ & 4. $\int u^n d u = \frac{u^{n+1}}{n + 1} + 
      C, \quad n \neq -1$ \\
      5. $\int \frac{d}{u} = ln \mid u \mid + C$ & 6. $\int e^u d u = e^u 
      + C$ \\
      7. $\int sin \quad u \quad du = -cos u + C$ & 8. $\int cos \quad u 
      \quad d u = sin \quad u + C$ \\
      9. $\int tan \quad u \quad du = -ln \mid cos \quad u \mid + C$ & 
      10. $\int cot \quad u \quad du = ln \mid sin \quad u \mid + C$ \\
      11. $\int sec \quad u \quad du = ln \mid sec \quad u + tan \quad du 
      \mid + C$ & 12. $\int csc \quad u \quad du = -ln \mid csc \quad u + 
      cot \quad u \mid + C$ \\
      13. $\int sec^2 u \quad du  = tan \quad u + C$ & 14. $\int csc^2 
      \quad u \quad du = -cot \quad u + C$ \\
      15. $\int sec \quad u \quad tan \quad u \quad du = sec \quad u + C$ 
      & 16. $\int csc \quad u \quad cot \quad du = -csc \quad u + C$ \\
      17. $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{a^2 - u^2}} = arcsin \frac{u}{a} + C$ & 
      18. $\int \frac{du}{a^2 + u^2} = \frac{1}{a} arctan \frac{u}{a} + 
      C$ \\
      19. $\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{u^2 - a^2}} = \frac{1}{a} arcsec 
      \frac{\mid u \mid}{a} + C$ \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

I am working toward this:

[image]

Some of the lines aren't centered, and the resizing isn't perfect, but you can fiddle with the resizing. I'll try to figure out how to center the lines properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your effort is greatly appreciated! Although I can't see it as complete? Should I first enter maybe all the data I have and then try to style it? I am trying to get something like this http://image.slidesharecdn.com/derivativesandintegralschartbasic-140105133027-phpapp02/95/derivatives-and-integrals-chart-basic-1-638.jpg?cb=1388928654

Comment: @DusanJ. I think I've made a result that's pretty close to what you want, all that's left is to center the lines. Tell me what you think, or if there's anything big I'm missing.